# Computed Column Based on Other Columns

Tags: c#, vb.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset, xtrareport

I have a `Dataset` with a Bunch of Columns used in a `Report (DevExpress XtraReports)` (DataSet being the DataSource). The Dataset has many columns, and i need to read a column (based on the row type), and decide which column value to read for the row, and apply formatting based on the row type.

## Example:

### DataSet

```
DataType    IntValue    RealValue   StringValue DateValue
Int32           123
DateTime                                        1/1/2011 1:23 AM
String                              XYZ
...
```

If the Datatype is DateTime, i need to read the DateValue column value, etc

I know we can use DataSet Expressions on computed columns, but cant find a way to apply the required Expression, and Format Data for the Report.

Is there a suggested way to handle this in the Report or at DataSet Level (excepting the formatting part)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are taking this approach. This dataset is filled from a SQL datasource or some sort of backend? if that is the case, why don't you just get the computed column in the right format from the SQL directly? Wouldn't be a performance overhead to loop through all records to try and compute the "right" column?

Since it is a report, wouldn't displaying the data be enough? if you really need to use the type, you can bring that from sql as well, so you end up only with two columsn, type and data. If you can elaborate a little bit more on what you are trying to do, it will be helpful.

Comment: i totally agree with you, and that was my point too, except the DBA is adamant that the Data cannot be formatted to one Datatype, as data may loose precision (if double is the only column returned, int looses precision, etc). Our main reason to take this approach is we have data of different data types, and based on the datattype, report need to format the data appropriately and generate parameter/Value pairs.

Comment: in that case, it may be better to build one stored procedure per report bring what it just needs. Sometimes too much generalization is also bad. You should build a framework for reports that knows how to talk to the corresponding stored proc and render the report based on the type. You may have additional constraints, but just a thought.

Comment: we are reviewing several other options. id post the approach we adpot :)